# Xamarin app shows black screen on ios11

Tags: ios, xamarin

An application, which works perfectly in simulator on iOS10 shows black screen after slash screen on iOS 11.
Also on real device it shows splash and then black screen, but here I don't have a spare device with iOS10 to confirm it will work differently on older iOS.

Any hint, what could be done to get it running on ios11?

Clarification: I had this application running on ios11 too, but when I needed to fix something in the app, and started Xamarin Studio after long time (since Jan'17), there were a lot of component updates. And now the App shows black screen after splash...

Answer (score 1):

1. Try to do real clean (delete bin & obj folder) for each project & right click on solution & choose clean {your solution name}. After it is done, right click on solution again & choose rebuild {your solution name}. After all done, try to debug on iOS11 simulator/ device.
2. If option no.1 is not working, maybe you can try to do breakpoint in finished launching method to see is it everything is working.

Comment: Thanks for the hint! Unfortunately it didn't help.
When I debug - it looks like the controllers/views are instantiated, but not shown. And [what confuses me completely] this is only on ios11, older versions work well.
Note: I had this application running on ios11 too, but when I needed to fix something in the app, and started Xamarin Studio after long time (since Jan'17), there were a lot of component updates. And now the App shows black screen after splash...

Comment: super weird, since you mention using Xamarin Studio, have you tried using Visual Studio for Mac for developing? Since they already discontinued updating Xamarin Studio.

Comment: yes, during update of Xamarin Studio, it offered to install VS for Mac. I did install it, but results are the same. Actually I don't see much difference between X-Studio and VS. Just a little bit different UI.

Answer (score 1):

I figured this out after a few hours.

My issue was at the Info.plist, below what I did on Visual studio for windows:

1. Right click on the info.plist and select Open with
2. Choose iOS manifest editor
3. Click on the tab visual effect
4. Go to the Launch Images
5. Make sure the option Source and Launch Screen are set up properlly
6. Clean your entire solution
7. Rebuild project
8. Try again

in my case Source was set as none.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sLv8n.png)

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me:

> Step 1. Replaced the info.plist with that from a fresh new project.
>
> Step 2. Edit only those fields in the file to its original content
> which matters (like package name, permissions, etc.)

I am suspecting the below piece of code in info.plist to have caused the issue:

```
<key>UIApplicationSceneManifest</key>
<dict>
    <key>UIApplicationSupportsMultipleScenes</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```